# I can not access an attribute of a json object in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I can access the name, type and genres attributes, but the image.medium attribute returns "null is not an object".I believe my error is related to the image attribute without composite by a json object, with two attributes, I am beginner in react-native and I do not know how to solve.

```
export default class ListaItens extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listaItens: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=Vikings')
      .then((response) => {
        // handle success
        this.setState({ listaItens: response.data })
        //console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        // handle error
        console.log("Erro ao recuperar dados");
      })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.listaItens.map(item => {
          return (
            <Itens key={item.show.id} item={item}> </Itens>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class Itens extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.item.show.image.medium }</Text>
                <Text>{this.props.item.show.name} </Text>
                <Text>{this.props.item.show.type} </Text>
                <Text>{this.props.item.show.genres} </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do all items in data set have that property and all have a string value? You might need a conditional render or add a "no image" url

Comment: all have the picture.

Comment: What does it show when you try to display `this.props.item.show.image` instead of `this.props.item.show.image.medium`?

Comment: I get this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys (medium, original) if you meant to render a collection of children, use array instead.

Comment: What was the response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand very well the structure here but I reached this.props.item.show.image.medium as below

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    listaItens:
[
{
  show:{
         'id':29,
         'url':"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/29/vikings",
         'name':'Vikings',
         'type': "Scripted",
         'language':'English',
         'genres':[  ],
         'status':'Running',
         'runtime':60,
         'premiered':'2013-03-03',
         'officialSite':'http://www.history.com/shows/vikings',
         'schedule':{  },
         'rating':{  },
         'weight':98,
         'network':{  },
         'webChannel':null,
         'externals':{  },
         'image':{
            'medium':'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/172/431187.jpg',
            'original':'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/172/431187.jpg'
         },
       }
     }
   ],
};

  render() {
      return (
        <View>
  {this.state.listaItens.map(item => {
    return (
      <Itens key={item.show.id} item={item} />
    );
  })}
</View>
      );
  }
}

  class Itens extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.image.medium }</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.name} </Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.type} </Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.genres} </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

And on the other hand, I assume that you have already separate components and use them as below,

//ListaItens Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Itens from './example';

export default class ListExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    listaItens:
[
    {
  show:{
         'id':29,
         'url':"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/29/vikings",
         'name':'Vikings',
         'type': "Scripted",
         'language':'English',
         'genres':[  ],
         'status':'Running',
         'runtime':60,
         'premiered':'2013-03-03',
         'officialSite':'http://www.history.com/shows/vikings',
         'schedule':{  },
         'rating':{  },
         'weight':98,
         'network':{  },
         'webChannel':null,
         'externals':{  },
         'image':{
            'medium':'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/172/431187.jpg',
            'original':'http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/172/431187.jpg'
         },
       }
     }
   ],
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <View>
  {this.state.listaItens.map(item => (
      <Itens key={item.show.id} item={item} />
    ))}
</View>
      );
  }
}
```

//Itens Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Itens extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.image.medium }</Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.name} </Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.type} </Text>
            <Text>{this.props.item.show.genres} </Text>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

[Lastly, this link could be helpful for you to have a better understanding.](https://github.com/cht8687/react-listview-sticky-header/issues/6)

Hope that this would be helpful...

Comment: Sorry, I left my question somewhat confused, I'm not only able to access the value of the image attribute of my API, other values such as name, genres and type are being searched normally, I updated my code to be clearer.

Comment: the way you did I get the following error, "null is not an object".

Comment: the problem is in your data , I just fetched the data check the results , some of your items does not return image genre, they return just null , so you should put a control in your code to filter these null results and return for example 'no image link' , you can do that in your Itens component .